# Are versions returned by AWS Lambda ListVersionsByFunction sorted?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go

When submitting a [`ListVersionsByFunction`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_ListVersionsByFunction.html) request to the AWS REST API is there any guarantee that the results will be sorted in any way?

If not, is there any way to get the most recent N versions without retrieving the entire list?

Without knowing this fact, I used to get the latest 1024 version (based on the assumption that it will take a long time for my code to generate that many versions) and sorted them in reverse order by some custom sorting function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first index in the resultset will be `$LATEST`, with subsequent versions in order from oldest to latest (e.g. sorted by `Version`, ascending).

Comment: Is there any guarantee over that?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking. Are you concerned about breaking changes to the API without warning, or are you experiencing a case where things don't behave as you expect?

Comment: I built my code based on the behaviour you are describing and yes, I worry breaking changes could appear unnoticed.

Comment: AWS APIs typically use dates to make sure requests get back payloads that match when they were created, so you can lock to a date if you are concerned. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/locking-api-versions.html (link to js docs but same idea for go)

Comment: That said, if you think about this particular API, I don't think the behavior will change. The version IDs/ARNs are sequential anyway, so showing them in this order is likely the fastest way, and putting $LATEST somewhere else would result in unnecessary/unused calls to page through records